# It keeps telling me that this object has no len in leetcode 35. Search Insert Position

Tags: python, python-3.x, solver, diamond-problem

it keeps giving me this error can you tell me why. I can't find the answer

```py
class Solution:
    def searchInsert(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
        x = len(List)
        for i in range(x):
            if List[i] == target:
                return i
            elif List[i] > target:
                return List[i-1]
```

**TypeError: object of type '_SpecialGenericAlias' has no len()**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not checking the length of nums, you're trying to check the lenght of List which is just an alias.

Replace `x = len(List)` with `x = len(nums)`

Answer (score 2):

`len(List)` is trying to check the `len` of the type alias `List` (which is used only for type hinting).

Even `len(list)` would have been wrong as it was trying to check the `len` of the `list` type.

The check should be `len(nums)` as `nums` is the name of variable that holds the actual list.

Similarly, `List[i]` and `List[i-1]` should be `nums[i]` and `nums[i - 1]`.